Appendix 1 of "A Mathematical Theory of Communication"
In Appendix 1 of "A Mathematical Theory of Communication", Shannon states:

Let $N_i(L)$ be the number of blocks of symbols of length $L$ ending in state $i$.  Then we have
$$N_j(L)=\sum_{i,s}N_i(L-b_{ij}^{(s)})$$
where $b_{ij}^1,b_{ij}^2,\dots,b_{ij}^m$ are the length of the symbols which may be chosen in state $i$ and lead to state $j$.  These are linear difference equations and the behavior as $L\to\infty$ must be of the type
$$N_j=A_jW^L.$$
Substituting in the difference equation
$$A_jW^L=\sum_{i,s}A_iW^{L-b_{ij}^{(s)}}$$
or
$$A_j=\sum_{i,s}A_iW^{-b_{ij}^{(s)}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad(1)$$
$$\sum_i\left(\sum_sW^{-b_{ij}^{(s)}}-\delta_{ij}\right)A_i=0.\qquad(2)$$

where $\delta_{ij}$ was defined earlier in the paper as:

$\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and is zero otherwise.

I don't understand how the equation goes from (1) to (2).  Can someone help explain?

$$A_j=\sum_{i,s}A_iW^{-b_{ij}^{(s)}}$$
$$\sum_{i,s}A_iW^{-b_{ij}^{(s)}}=A_j$$
$$\sum_i\left(\sum_s A_iW^{-b_{ij}^{(s)}}\right)=A_j$$
$$\sum_i\left(\sum_s W^{-b_{ij}^{(s)}}\right)A_i=\sum_i A_i\delta_{ij}$$
$$\sum_i\left(\sum_sW^{-b_{ij}^{(s)}}-\delta_{ij}\right)A_i=0.$$

I think I get it.  Thanks!
